# Engine oil to use for a 1953 International Harvester (IH) R-110

Tags: oil-change, classic

I'm restoring an older truck and I'm assuming that regular engine oil is ok to use in an old vehicle like that.   Some people mention soft valve beds so the oil needs more zinc in it.

What type/brand/model of oil should I use in my old classic 1953 truck?

Answer (score 1):

It was lead in gasoline that lubricated the valve seats. When unleaded gas was introduced many engines suffered valve "recession" as valves seemed to grind down valve seats. No one had any idea of this benefit of lead regardless of what you read today. So any motor oil is unlikely to help as I don't know of any lead additives in oil and very little oil gets on the valve seats.  I think the problem was fixed by changing valve rotators and adding high alloy seat inserts.

Comment: The lead was more so for the valve guides, then the seats. Valve seats don't need lubricated like the guides do.